# Problem with PEAR Auth on linux machine

Tags: php, pear

I am having problems with PEAR Auth on a linux machine. On the windows machine where development took place there is no problem.

Users get the invalid username/password message which is displayed whenever the auth fails.

Did anyone had the same problem ?

Using MDB2 for the database connection.

Regards,

Comment: This is hard to answer. I'd love to help you if you were a little less vague. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say whether anyone has had the same problem as you've not provided enough details to even know what the problem actually is. I'd love to help you resolve this issue, but more information is needed before I can make a start ;-)

Comment: The problem starts from the time that a user changes his password using a form. After the password is changed then the authorization process fails. 

The user cannot be authenticated. The weird thing is that there is no problem on a windows machine, only on linux.